# Integrate Sharepoint task list with exchange server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, exchange-server-2010

First question is it possible or not? I have tried to search a lot on this topic but does not find a way to achieve this. I know how to integrate task list with outlook but I want to integrate it with exchange server. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to integrate Sharepoint task list with exchange server.

You can follow the steps given below to perform the integration task:

1. Go to the SharePoint Central Administration website page.
2. Click Configuration Wizards on the Quick Launch.
3. Launch the farm configuration wizard.
4. Choose whether you want to opt into the Customer Experience Improvement Program (if offered as an option), and then click OK.
5. Click the Start the Wizard button.
6. Scroll to the bottom of the list of services, check the Work Management Service check box, and then click Next. (Note: you can also turn on Search Service from here and verify that User Profile Service is on, just check the boxes.)
7. Let the wizard finish. You can skip the site collection creation step, if you want.

Comment: I have not seen Work Management Service in my service list can you tell me reason for that. One more question In all the steps we are not providing any kind of exchange configuration which list to configuration so I am little confused about it can you please explain it further

Comment: Work Management service is new in SharePoint 2013. :(

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no standard way how to do it. As you mentioned each user can connect task list to his Outlook as another task source.

In one project I created workflow activity that creates tasks in users' exchange profiles but they needed to set permissions for sharepoint service account. This permissions can not be set by group policies or Exchange admin. It must be done individually.